# List/Tuple sorting issue in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a newbie to programming and I'm creating a matchmaking program, to compare personality scores I'm using lists to store, here is my code:

```
`ps = int(personality_score)
potential_partners = partners.Partners()
while potential_partners.available():
partner = []
personality_scores = []
a = potential_partners.get_name()
f = int(potential_partners.get_personality_score())
if ps == f:
print("This is your match" + a)
else:
g = abs(int(ps - f))
h = int(g)
personality_scores.append(h)
partner.append(a)
partner_compatability =list(zip(personality_scores, partner))
partner_compatability.sort(key = operator.itemgetter(0))
for sub in partner_compatability:
print(sub)`
```

I've looked at multiple questions and answers related to this and none are working for me, my output from the list is this:

```
`[['Mary Smith', 1]]
[['Juan Lopez', 5]]
[['Leslie Liu', 11]]
[['Tatiana Ivanov', 15]]
[['Andre Leroy', 11]]
[['Sam Augusta', 7]]
[['Adalbert Weber', 1]]`
```

but should be ordered from lowest score to highest:

```
`[['Mary Smith', 1]] 
[['Adalbert Weber', 1]]
[['Juan Lopez', 5]]
[['Sam Augusta', 7]]
[['Leslie Liu', 11]]
[['Andre Leroy', 11]]
[['Tatiana Ivanov', 15]]`
```

Comment: What do you think `sorted(sublist[1:], key = int)` does? What is the input and what output (how related to this input) you expect?

Comment: `sorted_list = [[sublist[0]] + sorted(sublist[1:], key = lambda x: x[1]) for sublist in partner_compatability]`. Why do you break off the `sublist[0]` btw?

Comment: this was a last resort piece of code i used from a question to get it working, ive tried using sort() and sorted in many ways

Answer (score 0):

(I'm also a newbie programmer and till there is a better answer) you could do what I did: just reverse the order and then sort.

```
lst = [['Mary Smith', 1],
['Juan Lopez', 5],
['Leslie Liu', 11],
['Tatiana Ivanov', 15],
['Andre Leroy', 11],
['Sam Augusta', 7],
['Adalbert Weber', 1]]
```

Then:

```
sorted_lst = [[k,v] for v,k in lst]
sorted_lst.sort()
print(sorted_lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly sort the `partner_compatability`

```
sorted_list = partner_compatability.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

I tried like this, as there are no list values provided

```
In [67]: a
Out[67]: [8, 9, 3]
In [68]: b
Out[68]: [5, 6, 3]

In [69]: partner_compatability = list(zip(a, b))

In [70]: partner_compatability
Out[70]: [(8, 5), (9, 6), (3, 3)]

In [71]: partner_compatability.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
In [72]: partner_compatability
Out[72]: [(3, 3), (8, 5), (9, 6)]
```

From your comment,

```
partner_compatability = [[(1, 'Mary Smith')],
 [(5, 'Juan Lopez')],
 [(11, 'Leslie Liu')],
 [(15, 'Tatiana Ivanov')],
 [(11, 'Andre Leroy')],
 [(7, 'Sam Augusta')],
 [(1, 'Adalbert Weber')]]

partner_compatability.sort(key=lambda x: x[0][0])

In [71]: partner_compatability
Out[71]:
[[(1, 'Mary Smith')],
 [(1, 'Adalbert Weber')],
 [(5, 'Juan Lopez')],
 [(7, 'Sam Augusta')],
 [(11, 'Leslie Liu')],
 [(11, 'Andre Leroy')],
 [(15, 'Tatiana Ivanov')]]
```

Comment: match("23")
None
None
None
None
None
None
None

Comment: can you print your partner_compatability

Comment: Woops, I meant to say that was the output of that code, I obviously have an error somewhere

Comment: this is the print of the compatability[(1, 'Mary Smith')]
[(5, 'Juan Lopez')]
[(11, 'Leslie Liu')]
[(15, 'Tatiana Ivanov')]
[(11, 'Andre Leroy')]
[(7, 'Sam Augusta')]
[(1, 'Adalbert Weber')]

Comment: Can you edit the question and add `partner_compatability`. Is it list of lists or list of tuples? The above comment is not helpful.

Comment: I edited the question to include most of the function

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator

data = [
    ['Mary Smith', 1],
    ['Juan Lopez', 5],
    ['Leslie Liu', 11],
    ['Tatiana Ivanov', 15],
    ['Andre Leroy', 11],
    ['Sam Augusta', 7],
    ['Adalbert Weber', 1],
]

data.sort(key = operator.itemgetter(1))
for sub in data:
    print(sub)
```

prints

```
['Mary Smith', 1]
['Adalbert Weber', 1]
['Juan Lopez', 5]
['Sam Augusta', 7]
['Leslie Liu', 11]
['Andre Leroy', 11]
['Tatiana Ivanov', 15]
```

Though not well known, the operator function should be faster than the equivalent lambda.  There is also `attrgetter`.  Both can be used when the key should be a tuple of multiple items.

Comment: im still getting the same output, without it being sorted. Are there any errors in the above code?

Comment: The code I posted produced the output shown, with 3.6.1.  Both were copied and pasted, not retyped.